# jQuery - Use multiple data search selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some checkboxes, and I want to filter all my DOM elements according to these filters.

My HTML is like :

```
<div data-year="2018">....</div>
<div data-year="2018">...</div>
<div data-year="2019">...</div>
```

When I click my checkboxes (I can have several checkboxes checked), I build a string like :

```
var search = '[data-years="2018"], [data-years="2019"], [data-years="2021"]';
```

My question is : how can I select all my `div` in jQuery ?

I tried something like :

```
var $div = $('div').find(search);
```

But no success. How can I select all years checked ?

Comment: Hi , you mean [like](https://jsfiddle.net/gyrw4aue/) this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has two problem:

1. The elements has `data-year` attribute but selector in variable used `data-years`.
2. You used [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method that trying to find childs elements in selector but the selector (`$("div")`) hansn't any child.

So you need to use variable as selector like `$(search)` or use [`.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) if you want to search on div tags only.

```
var $div = $(search);
// Or search on divs only
var $div = $('div').filter(search);
```

```js
var search = '[data-year="2018"], [data-year="2019"], [data-year="2021"]';
$(search).css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-year="2018">2018</div>
<div data-year="2018">2018</div>
<div data-year="2019">2019</div>
<div data-year="2020">2020</div>
<div data-year="2021">2021</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the .filter() or .siblings() functions